# Nginx multiple Apps on same port reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location

I'm trying to run a django app and and angular one on my VPS using Nginx. Below is my config file code:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.the-patron.com the-patron.com;
    charset utf-8;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /staticfiles/ {
        root /root/thepatron/The-Patron-Backend;
    }

    # Django Backend
    location /back/ {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/root/thepatron/The-Patron-Backend/thepatron.sock;
    }

    # Angular Frontend
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4200/;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Here my Angular app is running well and the Django one isn't. If I change `location /backend/` to `location /` on line 12 and `location /` to `location /frontend/` on line 18 then I will get the Django app to run while the Angular app will not.

How can I run both and change the location of each?

Comment: One thing I see totally incorrect is you are not serving Angular application as static files, which you should do by creating a Angular app build and serving static files over ngnix.

Comment: @Vipulw how am i supposed to do so?

Comment: You should build your angular app and server the static files. Also if your Django backend is running on a port number, you need to then use the configuration you used for Angular as above

Answer (score 0):

As my previous approach to host my `Angular` and `Django` apps separately was totally wrong. I finally managed to solve my issue thanks to the comments of `@Vipulw` above.

What worked for me is that I built my `Angular` application to production and placed the generated build folder inside my static files folder in my `Django` app directory, and then configured my `Nginx` to serve that `Angular` build.

Below is my new `Nginx` config file:

```
# Angular Reverse Proxy
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name <Domain name or IP address>;


    root /root/<path to Django app>/static/<Angular app build folder>;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
 }
}

# Django Reverse Proxy
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name <Domain name or IP address>;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/root/<path to Django app>/<myapp>.sock;
    }
}
```

**Additional Note:**

In this way mentioned above, my `Angular` app is running on `port 80` while my `Django` app is running on `port 8080`. Everything is working fine this way but I don't see that as the best way to do run both `Angular` and `Django`. After a little bit of research, I found that the best way to serve `Angular and Django` in `one app` is to let the default `Django` route to point to the `Angular` build. The default `Django` route right now is pointing to the `Django Rest Framework root directory`.

**Sadly, I don't know how to let `Django's default route` to point to the `Angular build file` at the moment**.